# Simple Kendo grid cell Template to display cell data in no wrapped way with ending '...' and a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I would like to display longer text cells in no multiline and word wrapped mode, instead in a form: `|Alfred Fu... [mybutton]`|

Unfortunatelly I can not solve how to keep the ending '...' and the button in one line within the cell:

[image]

My custom working sample can be viewed and edited [here in Telerik dojo playground](http://dojo.telerik.com/ixILU/2)

I know the no word wrap can be achieved by CSS `white-space: nowrap;` I also know I should use column Template (`.ClientTemplate("...")` in ASP MVC). I am utilizing kendo templating infrastructure, so my template is not inline.

The column:

```
columns: [{
    ...
}, {
    field: "CompanyName",
    title: "Company Name",
    width: 100,
    template: "#=getClientViewTemplate(data.CompanyName)#",
}, {
   ....
}]
```

The kendo template (note: using bootstrap 3, what is referenced in the [working sample](http://dojo.telerik.com/ixILU/2) via maxcdn):

```
<script type="text/kendo-template" id="clientViewTemplate">
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    #=text# 
    <a href="" style="float: right" class=" btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span></a>
</span>
```

And the template provider javascript function:

```
<script>
    function getClientViewTemplate(data) {
        var template = kendo.template($('#clientViewTemplate').html());
        var result = template({ text: data });
        return result;
    }
</script>
```

I would like to keep those "...", and at the same time I would like to have the data and the button in one line within the cell. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the feeling (maybe I am wrong) that the automatic ... rendering comes from the *outer* `td`, which have `role=gridCell`, and measures the text length. So it hopeless to trick out. ...*unless* we have a dedicated `td` with `role=gridCell` for the text. The only way I could figure out is an embedded table with one row and two cells.

Here is what I've ended: [see in action](http://dojo.telerik.com/ixILU/8)

Style:

```
<style>
    table.clientViewTemplate td span
    {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    table.clientViewTemplate td
    {
        border: 0px; // No border for our embedded table
        padding: 0px; // No padding for our embedded table
    }

    table.clientViewTemplate td:nth-child(2)
    {
         width: 24px; // TODO: The button width should not hardcoded
    }
</style>
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/kendo-template" id="clientViewTemplate">
    <table class="clientViewTemplate">
        <tr>
            <td role="gridCell">
                <span>
                    #=text#
                </span>
            </td>
            <td role="gridCell">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this, give styles.
Like this css:

```
.widthStyle
{
     width: 50px;
     overflow: hidden; 
     white-space: nowrap; 
     text-overflow: ellipsis; 
     float:left;
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="widthStyle">
    #=text#   
</div>
<a href="" style="width:12px; float:left;" class=" btn btn-info btn-xs"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span></a>
```

this is working, [link](http://dojo.telerik.com/ixILU/9)

Comment: egvrcn: thx, your sample is here as I see http://dojo.telerik.com/ixILU/5 Unfortunately the button covers the right ending of the text. I think somehow we must trick to believe the span it have less space, but this is not working currently...